# In-place editing with GwtQuery

Tags: java, jquery, jquery-ui, gwt, gwtquery

How to I do in-place editing with `GwtQuery`?

Are there any plugins available? Something similar to XEditable:

http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/demo.html

Where there is Jquery-UI plugin for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately gwtquery and jquery cannot share plugins.

X-editable has to be ported to gwt before you could use it in gquery.

If someone is interested on [contributing gquery plugins](https://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/wiki/WritingPlugins) it's welcome.

There is a project, though, which will help to port jquery plugins to gquery reusing almost the original js plugin code. This module is called [JsQuery](https://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/wiki/JsQuery) and it is very advanced.